# How to replace symbol from the Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, javascript-framework

This is my code, but this is not working.

It is showing the following  error:

> `lanlatvalue.replace` is not a function.

How to correct it?

```
var lanlatvalue =(25.2465,15.3686);
var latlngStrs = lanlatvalue.replace(/\(|\)/g,"").split(",",2);
var latss = parseFloat(latlngStrs[0]);
var lngss = parseFloat(latlngStrs[1]);
alert(latss+lngss);
```

Comment: Maybe use an `Array` for the `lanlatvalue` variable, to make it more manageable: `[25.2465, 15.3686]`  and then work with individual `long` & `lat` but accessing the array by *index*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings must be quoted in JavaScript.

```
var lanlatvalue = "(25.2465,15.3686)";
```

Comment: this is correct or not?  var lanlatvalue = ''+latlan+'';

Comment: The string `"+latlan+"` would not match your replace pattern, or your split pattern, so the script would error when you tried to parseFloat on `undefined`.

Comment: so how do it? any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: you see: this is my function: function mapdetails(latlan)
    {
      //latlan=(25.213254,25.231546);//
     var lanlatvalue = "''+latlan+''"; 
     
           alert(lanlatvalue);
     var  latlngStrs = lanlatvalue.replace(/\(|\)/g,"").split(",",2); 
 
     var lats = parseFloat(latlngStrs[0]);
     var lngs = parseFloat(latlngStrs[1]);
     

     
     maps(lats,lngs);}

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your current problem is now. The code in the question doesn't work because you assign a number to a variable, and then have a number floating around as an expression doing nothing. The rest of the code then tries to treat the number as a string of comma separated data. If you made it a string of comma separated data (by adding quote marks) then it would work. Now you're reposting code, adding new code which does't make sense, and asking about "other ways", but you haven't said why you can't just fix the input to conform to what the code expects.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `var lanlatvalue = "(25.2465,15.3686)";` (quoted).

Comment: this is my code:function mapdetails(latlan) { //latlan=(25.213254,25.231546);// var lanlatvalue = "''+latlan+''"; alert(lanlatvalue); var latlngStrs = lanlatvalue.replace(/(|)/g,"").split(",",2); var lats = parseFloat(latlngStrs[0]); var lngs = parseFloat(latlngStrs[1]); maps(lats,lngs);}

Answer (score 0):

change thisline:

```
var lanlatvalue =(25.2465,15.3686);
```

to

```
var lanlatvalue ='(25.2465,15.3686)';
```